# Convert each digit from number saved in string to array of int

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, atoi

I'm writing this project on DFA and i want to save and covert each digit of an integer saved as a string  to an int array.This is the code from the function responsible for that:

---

```
int l=final_states.size();
int* temp_final;
temp_final=new int [l];
for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
    temp_final[i]=atoi(final_states.at(i).c_str());
}
```

---

This gives me the following mistake : `request for member 'c_str' in '((DFA*)this)->DFA::final_states.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::at<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((std::basic_string<char>::size_type)i))', which is of non-class type 'char'|`.

---

So if you could tell me how to make this conversion and saving work , that would be great.

Comment: `at` returns a `char`. You're calling `c_str` on that `char`. Perhaps you were just looking to do a single `std::transform`.

Comment: @chris I have never used *std::transform*, but if i give it *temp_final[i]=atoi( final_states.at(i));* which is logical it gives me this mistake * expected primary-expression before 'const'|*

Comment: `atoi` takes a string. Passing a character to it doesn't work. Anyway, I suggest trying to learn how to use the premade algorithms because they make your intent very clear, are bug-free, and are relentlessly tested for performance. A loop written on the fly is none of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `atoi()` function wants a `const char*`, you cannot call `.c_str()` with the result of `.at(i)` which is actually a `char&` value.

Just fix your assignment line to

```
 temp_final[i] = int(final_states[i]) - int('0');
```

Though you also might check if you really [have a *digit* there](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), before putting it into your result array:

```
 if(std::isdigit(final_states[i])) {
     temp_final[i] = int(final_states[i]) - int('0');
 }
 else {
     // Skip, or throw error ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`c_str()` doest not work because after calling `at(i)` you've got a char not a string. I suggest you to use:

```
temp_final[i]=final_states.at(i) - '0';
```

Here you take an ASCII code for a char symbol and when you subtract a `'0'` you get exectly an int you need, because all the digits go in order in ASCII [table](http://www.asciitable.com/).